# Volume using polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Find the volume V of the solid that: lies under the paraboloid $$z=4−x^2−y^2$$ and above the xy-plane. Also, what will change during your process if the solid lies inside and outside the cylinder given by $x^2+y^2≤1$ and $x^2+y^2≥1$, respectively? Set-up the integrals only in these two cases and sketch the corresponding regions.

So, I solved the initial question by integrating twice using polar coordinates, but the second half of this question has me confused. I'm not sure why anything changes if you give a function and state that the solid exists on both sides of it. Wouldn't the function not serve as a bound for the solid?

Comment: I think the question wants you to do it for each one seperatly.  So find the volume outside the cylinder as one question and find the volume inside as another question.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a problem setting up the integrals.  Inside or outside the the cylinder sets the limits for $r.$  Inside the cylinder you are bound by $r=1.$  On both side of the cylinder you are bound by $r =2.$  Just the region outside the cylinder is $1<r<2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For the first case, the projection of $z=4-x^2-y^2$ in the $xy$ plane is a disc with radius $2$, so:
  $$
  V = \iint_{D=\{(r,\theta)|0\le\theta\le 2\pi, \color{red}{0\le r\le 2}\}} (4-r^2)rdrd\theta
  $$
- For the second case, you are inside the cylinder with radius $1$, which is inside the disc with radius $2$, so
  $$
  V = \iint_{D=\{(r,\theta)|0\le\theta\le 2\pi, \color{red}{0\le r\le 1}\}} (4-r^2)rdrd\theta
  $$
- For the third case, you are outside the cylinder with radius $1$, and inside the disc with radius $2$, so
  $$
  V = \iint_{D=\{(r,\theta)|0\le\theta\le 2\pi, \color{red}{1\le r\le 2}\}} (4-r^2)rdrd\theta
  $$

Comment: Much appreciated, that helps a lot.